# Ruby on Rails 5: Find index of post_id and display in view (post # of n)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a resource `:posts`, which I show one at a time in show.html.erb

Suppose I have ten posts, each with an `:id` going from 1-10. If I delete post #2, then my posts will be `1,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10`. If I create ten posts and delete them all, then the next post `:id` would be `[1,3..10,21]` but I would only have 11 posts.

I want to show the post number that's in the application and put it in the view against a total number of posts. So if you were looking at post #3, it might have an `:id` of 3, but it is post #2 in the database.

Here's what I tried so far:

**posts_controller.rb**

```
def show 
    ...
    @post = Post.friendly.find(params[:id])
    @total_posts = Post.all.count.to_i

    @posts_array = Post.pluck(:id).to_a
    ...
end
```

views/posts/show.html.erb

```
<%= @post.id %> of <%= @total_posts %> /
```

models/post.rb

```
def next
  Post.where("id > ?", id).order(id: :asc).limit(1).first
end


def prev
  Post.where("id < ?", id).order(id: :desc).limit(1).first
end
```

However, showing the :id of a resource is a security issue so I don't know how to do it better.

How can I make it so the `show.html.erb` view only shows the current index order of the total amount of resources as compared to the `post_id`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to find the 'array index' of a record (so to speak) you can do this:

```
Agency.order(id: :asc).offset(params[:index]).limit(1)
```

You don't really want to do any other way because then it will load EVERY record into rails which will be very slow. It's better to ask the database for only a single record (which is what 'offset' does). Just replace `params[:index]` with whatever the name of the params is, whether its `params[:id]`, etc.

I did just want to address one thing you said:

> However, showing the :id of a resource is a security issue so I don't know how to do it better

That's not a security issue. The app should be designed in a way where the ID of a resource is not special or "secret." If you have an ID of a record, your controller should work such that it "authorizes" certain actions and won't let you do something you're not supposed to (like a user deleting a post).

If you REALLY need to do this, then just hide the ID and use a slug instead, like `example.com/this-is-a-post-slug`. This can be done [quite easily](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/creating-vanity-urls-in-rails)

**Edit** To answer your specific question...

```
ids = Agency.order(id: :asc).pluck(:id)
@post_index = ids.find_index(@post.id)
@next_post  = ids[@post_index + 1]
@prev_post  = ids[@post_index - 1]
```

You can now use `@post_index` in your view.

Note: `@prev_post` and `@next_post` will be `nil` when the page doesn't exist (i.e. the "next post" when you're on the last page), so you will need to check that.

Comment: I had some sense that generating an array of all the posts per view action was going to be crazy at some point, so thank you for pointing out the offset method to me. However, when I tried your solution I get this in my view, and it doesn't show the post_id as an index? I put this in my controller `@post_order = Post.order(id: :asc).offset(params[:id]).limit(1)`
but the view says this: `#Post::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007fd481bbeec0&gt; of 13`

Comment: Hmm, I see what you're asking now. I don't know much about your project but that's a very "roundabout" way of doing this. Are you sure that's what you really want to do? If you care to explain why it has to be like this (which is very akward) maybe we can give better suggestions. If not, I'll give you the original answer

Comment: I don't want to generate an array. I was just trying that because it made sense to me. What i want to do is show what post the user is looking at, with respect to its index order in the database. If I make 100 posts, and delete all but the first and last one, it'll be post id 1 and 100 available. But in the view, it would say post 100 of 2, which doesn't make sense. I want it to say post 2 because it's the second post in the database, not because of its id.

Comment: I answered your original question above. Fetching all ID's is fine here because it doesnt instantiate records, and even result sets of multiple thousands will still be fast.

Comment: Edited my answer

Comment: Thank you. I had to do this to get it working perfectly `<%= @post_index.to_i+1 %> `

Answer (score 2):

An efficient way to do this could be

```
# app/controllers/posts_controller.rb
def show
  @post = Post.friendly.find(params[:id])
  @total_posts = Post.count
  @post_index = Post.where("id <= ?", @post.id).count
end

# app/views/posts/show.html.erb
. . .
<%= @post_index %> of <%= @total_posts %>
. . .
```

You should avoid loading all posts (or even their `id`) if you can.  This will become more and more expensive as the number of posts grows and will eventually become a bad bottleneck for performance.

Comment: This does not work. PG::InvalidTextRepresentation at /posts/23t2t2
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "23t2t2"
LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "posts" WHERE (id <= '23t2t2')
                                                  ^ -- I understand your point though, loading all posts wasn't a good idea.

Comment: @mazing So your `posts.id` column is not an integer type?

Comment: Rails automatically generates a posts_id column, i'm not sure if its integer or string.

Comment: Can you check the id type in the migrations (or the database itself)?

Comment: The schema says this ```create_table "posts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text "title"
    t.text "text"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "user_id"
    t.string "integer"
    t.string "slug"
    t.index ["slug"], name: "index_posts_on_slug", unique: true
  end```

Comment: @SimpleLime thanks for the tip.  I wasn't sure what might be going on here because I was not familiar with the FriendlyId gem.  I have updated my answer to use `@post.id` as you suggested because I agree with you.

Answer (score 1):

Just try it:

```
def show 
...
@post = Post.friendly.find(params[:id])
@total_posts = Post.count # this will return integer type data

@posts_array = Post.pluck(:id) # you don't need to_a as .pluck returns array
...
```

For the next part you could write:

```
def next
  self.class.where("id > ?", id).limit(1).first # this use of id is secured.
end


def prev
  self.class.where("id < ?", id).order(id: :desc).limit(1).first
end
```

Comment: This did not do anything, but thank you helping me clean up my controller methods! :)